# Box v2 API - Basic questions

Tags: box-api

I have a fairly basic question regarding the new Box API v2.

I have developed a Firefox extension (FEBE) that performs automatic, scheduled, unattended backups of the user's Firefox profile.  These backups can (optionally) be automatically uploaded to the user's Box account.  I currently use the v1 API and it has been working fine for several years.  I now see the v1 API is being deprecated in December, 2013.  Does this mean it will no longer work, or that it is just no longer supported?

If I have to re-write my code (JavaScript) to handle the v2 API, will I still be able to provide the upload capability without any user intervention?  FEBE securely stores the user's Box username and password and silently logs in to initiate the upload.  From what I've been able to research so far, it seems the OAuth 2 verification process requires an interstitial page to confirm the users credentials.  Is this true?  If so, that would remove the 'unattended' aspect of the backup.

Also, can anyone recommend a good source of JavaScript code snippets that show examples of the Box v2 API in action (preferably not JQuery, just plain, old-fashion JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean it will no longer work, or that it is just no longer supported?

Yes, in December 2013 the V1 API will cease to function in its entirety.

> …will I still be able to provide the upload capability without any user intervention?

The user will need to go through an initial web flow *once* to authorize your use of their account. After that, you can perform everything in the background.

There aren't any good sources of sample JS that I'm aware of, hopefully someone else can chime in on that.